# Increase serial number in php posting

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am using one HTML form to fetch the data in php code.  Below is the PHP code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sl); $i++) {
$email_body .= "SL:" . $sl[$i] . "NAME:" . $name[$i] . "EMAIL:" . $mail[$i] . "\n";
}
```

This gives the output in he following format:

```
SL   NAME    EMAIL
0    Peter   peterxyz@xyz.com
1    Purker  purker234@xyz.com
```

But what I need it in following format:

```
SL   NAME    EMAIL
1    Peter   peterxyz@xyz.com
2    Purker  purker234@xyz.com
```

I can rectify the code by writing "$i=1;" but it is not the correct solution, as this is code again being used in javascript. Hence, please advise me how can I make SL as 1 when $i =0. Kindly help me please?

Comment: What is SL? Where does it come from?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but it might be better using foreach($sl) instead of a for loop.

Comment: SL is nothing but the serial number (i.e starts from 1,2,3,4......

Comment: @guruje Then why is SL in an array? Clearly it doesn't start from 1 or you'd get the output you expect. Once again, where does SL come from? Post the code that begings `$sl =`.

Comment: sl, name, mail comes from html dynamic form.

Comment: it s not very clear , can't understand what you expect precisley

Comment: I want  a simple serial number ($sl)  for each row. This just for numbering only. noway this $sl is required in the script code

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `($i = 1; $i <= count($sl); $i++)`, it's more readable that what you're trying to do, but as said, you want a foreach

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you in this case:

```
$a = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sl); $i++) {    
    $email_body .= "SL:" . $a++ . "NAME:" . $name[$i] . "EMAIL:" . $mail[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/317273

Comment: Because `$sl[a]` on the final loop won't exist, it will create an error.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit more? @Styphon

Comment: Have a look at this eval - https://eval.in/317211

As you can see all that happens is the first element in the array is skipped and on the last loop `$sl[$a]` doesn't exist. You can't just change the key you're outputting and expect the content of $sl to have changed.

Comment: what about now? @Styphon

Answer (score -1):

looks like your $sl is 0 indexed and should be 1 indexed, you could do

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sl); $i++) {
    $email_body .= "SL:" . $sl[$i] + 1 . "NAME:" . $name[$i] . "EMAIL:" . $mail[$i] . "\n";
}

or 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($sl); $i++) {
    $email_body .= "SL:" . $sl[$i + 1] . "NAME:" . $name[$i] . "EMAIL:" . $mail[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: That second for loop will error as `$sl[count($sl)]` won't exist, but on the very last loop that's what you'll be checking for.

Comment: If I put $sl +1, it works for first row as SL:1 but for second row, it shows SL:3 and for the third row: SL: 4

Comment: sounds like $sl isn't what you expect it is

Comment: is there any  correction for getting sl (serial number, auto generated) - so that, we can omit in the code?

Comment: your loop is logging $sl correctly, $sl must not be what you expect, I assume `$sl[0] == 0`